# Streaming data from one Lambda to another

Tags: amazon-web-services, sorting, aws-lambda, amazon-sns

I want to build a distributed implementation of [Samplesort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samplesort) using [AWS Lambda](https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/) functions for a 100GB dataset made of two columns (key and sorted value), each encoded using 64-bit floats. The dataset is to be distributed across 220 Lambda functions, each having 1GB of RAM, with 28.4M rows per function. Each Lambda can sort its subset within less than a second. From there, we send 220 × 220 = 48,400 equally distant samples to a root Lambda through 220 SNS messages (30ms to 50ms), have the root Lambda sort them (less than 2ms), then broadcast 220 equally distant samples to the sorting Lambda functions over SNS (30ms).

The hard part is to then have all the sorting Lambdas send portions of their respective datasets to the right sorting Lambdas. This requires that the full 100GB dataset be moved across the sorting Lambdas, with 220 × 219 = 48,180 individual data movements. My question is the following: what is the fastest way of doing that?

Using EFS would give me about 469MB/s of aggregated write bandwidth, which would take about 213s. Reads are about 20 times faster, therefore would require an extra 11s. S3 would be a lot faster. We know that read throughput of S3 from a Lambda is about 75MB/s. If we assume a similar write throughput (probably overly optimistic) and Parquet compression with a 5× compression factor, we get 375MB/s of read/write throughput. Each Lambda would need to write then read 454MB of data, which would require 2.42s.

A faster approach would be to have pairs of sorting Lambda functions communicate through WebSocket. Is that possible? If so, what is the proper way to configure it? If not, what would be an alternative that would not require the use of a slow persistence layer?

Note: this [article](https://brunomaga.github.io/Distributed-Sort) gives a great introduction to the distributed Samplesort.

Comment: Have you considered s3?

Comment: @DanielFarrell It would still be quite slow, but I'll model it for the sake of argument.

Comment: Though it does have higher latency, unlike EFS, S3 parallelizes very well (and without any inherent upper limit to throughput)  because it doesn't have to offer filesystem consistency.  Put all the data in S3 and process it there, maybe in a columnar format to speed things up.  220 lambda might be less than what would give optimal performance - doesn't have to be same number of lambdas at every step, right?

Comment: @DanielFarrell I think you're right. I updated my original question. The numbers look really good if you can write as fast as you can read. Do you have a sense of whether this is the case or not?

Comment: @IsmaelGhalimi is it possible that your question falls into the criteria of a "XY Problem" (https://xyproblem.info/)? Seems a little odd to move 100GB dataset at once after dealing with 384KB(n) portions.

Comment: @noamyg I don't think so. The following [article](https://brunomaga.github.io/Distributed-Sort) might help understand the approach.

Comment: I don't have a meaningful comparison or read and write speed, but both should be in the 50MB/s range or so.

Comment: @DanielFarrell Awesome! I'll start with that. Then WebSocket would probably be overkill., because S3 intermediation still remains within the same order of magnitude as the local sorts. Thank you so much!